# Nuget $project.Object.References.Add fails in install PS-script

Tags: .net, powershell, nuget, nuspec

I have my nuget package, lets call it **A** that has a dependency on another public package **Nunit.Runners**

When A depends on Nunit.Runners it doesn't add the assemblies I need into my project, the assemblies I depend on are in **NUnit.Runners.2.6.3\tools\lib** so, because nuget only adds referces to assemblies in lib, I think I need to add a Install.ps1 to my nuget package

I now have

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$NunitRunners = join-path -path $packagesFolder -childpath "NUnit.Runners.2.6.3"

$project.Object.References.Add($NunitRunners+"\nunit.core")
$project.Object.References.Add($NunitRunners+"\nunit.core.interfaces")
```

But it's throwing

```
 Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Unspecified error
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))" At

 + $project.Object.References.Add <<<< ($NunitRunners+"nunit.core.dll")
     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
```

Any pointers as to why this is throwing on "Add" super welcome

My install.ps1 (here for reference)

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

write-host "Install path" $installPath
$packagesFolder = Split-Path -Path $installPath -Parent
write-host "packages folder" $packagesFolder
write-host $toolsPath
write-host $package

$NunitRunners = join-path -path $packagesFolder -childpath "NUnit.Runners.2.6.3"
write-host $NunitRunners
$project.Object.References.Add($NunitRunners+"\nunit.core")
$project.Object.References.Add($NunitRunners+"\nunit.core.interfaces")
```

BTW I just need to reference those two assemblies, I don't need to reference nunit.framework

NOTE: I did see [this](https://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/266178) thread in codeplex but nothing there pointed to a solution (ie the  project is not client profile and the assemblies shouldn't be on the GAC)

Comment: What's the full path for $NunitRunners? It looks like it is missing the `tools\lib` part so the paths to NUnit.Core.dll and NUnit.Core.Interfacesl.dll will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths to NUnit.Core.dll and NUnit.Core.Interfaces.dll are incorrect.

Currently **$NunitRunners** is pointing to `packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.3` when it should be pointing to `packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.3\tools\lib`.

So you can either change the $NunitRunners path or add it later on when you add the references:

```
 $project.Object.References.Add($NunitRunners+"\tools\lib\nunit.core.dll")
 $project.Object.References.Add($NunitRunners+"\tools\lib\nunit.core.interfaces.dll")
```

Comment: I m blind :D I also added some version info by iterating the package as in here https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/Installer/NuGetPackages/NUnit.Runners/Install.ps1

Answer (score 0):

So you have tried specifying the [NUnit.Runners 2.6.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit.Runners/) dependency in your [nuspec](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference) file and it doesn't work?  Have you tried specifying the [NUnit core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/) as a dependency as well?

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency id="NUnit" version="2.6.3" />
  <dependency id="NUnit.Runners" version="2.6.3" />
</dependencies>
```

If this doesn't work, you could also try including the NUnit dlls in the file section and include them in your package A, but that's not ideal.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I don't need a reference to NUnit on this package. I did add a dependency reference to NUnit.Runners as you have here. Install.ps1 is the recommended way to do crazy stuff like this and since this is for an OSS project I rather try the way it should be. Adding the dlls I need in the files section is not going to cut it.